# Prove that there does an infinite subset of a partially ordered set ℕ × ℕ(coordinatewise order), every 2 elements of which are incomparable.

Tags: set-theory

Excuse me for my Englando (and for the cliche, too).
Just wanted to check if my proof is legit.

Let's suppose there exists one, call it *S*. There are 2 cases of how *S* can be structured: either one of the sets of coordinates (meaning sets of first and second coordinates) is infinite and the other one is finite or both are infinite. If it's the former, then assume that there is infinite amount of unique second coordinates. Case when there are infinitely many unique first (but not second) coordinates is handled in a similar way by changing inequality signs.

I will consider 3 elements of a set: let's call them *s = (a, b), s′ = (c, d)* and *s′′ = (e, f)* (first unfixed).
Using axiom of choice, we choose *a* and *b* for *s*, such that b is the biggest second coordinate among all *S*. Then there are infinitely many such *s′* that *a ≤ c* and *b > d* (because of our choice of *b* and structure of *S*). Then we fix coordinates for *s′* so that there is infinitely many such *s′′ = (e, f)* for which *c > e* and *d ≤ f*.

Then we are left with 2 cases for coordinates of *s′′*: either we have (*a ≤ e* and *b > f*) or (*a > e* and *b ≤ f*). Notice that at least one set of such possible values of *s′′* (let's call these sets *S′⊂ S* and *S′′⊂ S*) is infinite (because set of all possible values for *s′′* is infinite in the first place).

If *S′* is infinite, then by simple arithmetic it follows that there are infinitely many such *s′′∈ S* that *a ≤ e < c* and *d ≤ f < b*, which contradicts the fact that *S′* is infinite, because both *e* and *f* have both lower and upper bounds.

If *S′′* is infinite, then  there are infinitely many such *s′′∈ S* that *e < a ≤ c* and *d < b ≤ f*. Since *b* is the biggest second coordinate and *c* has *a* as an upper bound (and we are dealing with natural numbers), we one again come to contradiction. So there is no such set *S*.

And by the way, I don't think my solution (if it's right in the first place) can be used to prove this statement in ℕ^k case (which is the next problem). What is the right way to do this then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument about choosing a *biggest* second coordinate $b$ is not compelling (or not until we already have established finiteness). Also, the proof does not need the Axiom of Choice.

The general statement can be proved by induction, the case $S\subset \Bbb N^0$ being trivial.

Let $S\subset \Bbb N^k$ be a set of pairwise incomparable elements.
For $1\le i\le k$ and $m\in\Bbb N$, let
$$Q_{i,m}=\{\,(x_1,\ldots, x_k)\in \Bbb N^k\mid x_i=m\,\}.$$
Then $Q_{i,m}$ is order-isomorphic (by dropping the $i$th coordinate) to $\Bbb N^{k-1}$. By induction hypothesis, $S\cap Q_{i,m}$ is finite for all $i$ and $m$.

Or, to express the same a bit differently: Given $i,m$ as above, let
$$S'=\{\,(x_1,\ldots, x_{k-1})\in \Bbb N^{k-1}\mid (x_1,\ldots, x_{i-1},m,x_{i+1},\ldots, x_k)\in S\,\}. $$
Then the elements of $S'$ are elementwise incomparable, hence by induction hypotheses $S'$ is finite, hence $S\cap Q_{i,m}$ is finite.

Assuming $S\ne \emptyset$, pick an element $\mathbf s=(s_1,\ldots, s_k)\in S$. Then with 
$$Q:=\bigcup_{1\le i\le k}\,\bigcup_{1\le m\le s_i}Q_{i,m},$$ 
the intersection $S\cap Q$ is still finite.
But if $\mathbf y=(y_1,\ldots, y_k)\in S$, with $\mathbf y\ne \mathbf s$, then then imcomparability condition implies that $y_i\le s_i$ for some $1\le i\le k$. In other words, $\mathbf y\in Q_{i,y_i}\subset Q$.
We conclude that $S\subset Q$ and so $S=S\cap Q$ is finite. $\square$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think I will need some clarifications. First, what is the statement that $Q_{i,m}$ is order-isomorphic to $ℕ^{k-1}$ used for? Induction step? Even if there is one, I can't catch it. I just see it being proved for some ordinary *k*. And second, where has this structure (meaning the $Q_{i,m}$ thing) of a proof come from? Is it something common in set theory? Or have you derived it on fly? Just wondering, lol. Thanks once again.

Comment: @MarkZakharovIt is used to conclude that when viewing $S\cap Q_{i,m}$ as subset of $\Bbb N^{k-1}$, we still have that no two elements are comparable; so that the induction hypothesis can be applied and $S\cap Q_{i,m}$ is finite.